# How do I set the default Elixir mix task

Tags: elixir-mix, elixir

If I have a `mix.exs` file something like:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.My_task do
  use Mix.Task

  @shortdoc "Perform my task"

  def run(_) do
    IO.puts "Working"
  end
end

defmodule ElixirKoans.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do

  ...    

end
```

I can happily run this with `mix my_task`.

How do I make `my_task` be the default, so it is executed when I run `mix` without a task?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like you can define inside the project block (mix.exs) using **default_task**:

```
def project do
  [default_task: "run"]
end
```

More info: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/f3f64cdba205253ca0bbc0ce6a5dddd500ffb48f/lib/mix/lib/mix/project.ex#L266-L280

Comment: Thank you for this.  I wish I could give you an extra +1 for highlighting the line numbers, I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: Nice! You can select lines on github using click and then shift + click :)

Comment: just in case anyone else had the same problem I did, this should go into mix.exs, not the mix task you have implemented.