# 'Task could not be found' for custom mix task

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have a task Thing in lib/mix/tasks/thing.exs

The code is:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Thing do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(_) do
    IO.puts "hello world"
  end

end
```

When I run `mix thing` or `mix Thing` I get `The task thing could not be found` or `The task Thing could not be found`

I've tried running `mix compile` beforehand, which didn't help.

I also tried putting the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073023/how-do-i-set-the-default-elixir-mix-task) directly into my mix.exs, as shown in that question. I still couldn't run the task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mix tasks need to be compiled. If you rename from `lib/mix/tasks/thing.exs` to `lib/mix/tasks/thing.ex` then it should work.

You can read more about scripted mode (.exs) at: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules.html#scripted-mode